# how to make my document file available to another user?

Tags: 17.10, file-sharing, shared-folders

ubuntu 17.1. As user one I have downloaded desktop images into my downloads folder. How can I make them available to user two?
I tried to do it by copying the files to public as user one. but when logging in as user two the files are not in public.
I would think the public folders for any/all users would be mutually shared.

I also tried to set user one and user two public folders as shared, but I do not see either folder being shared.

How to share specific folders/files between users?
thanks st

Answer (score 1):

User1's Public directory is not User2's Public directory. User1's Public directory is /home/user1/Public. User2's Public directory is /home/user2/Public. For User2 to access those files, that user is going to have to specify /home/user1/Public as the directory to look at. In addition, the permissions of Uer1's Public directory should allow it. To verify, as User2, type in a terminal window:

```
$ls /home/user1/Public
```

If you can see the files there, the permissions are set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make them available to user two?

Don't use the `/home/$USER/` directory for that.

- create a separate directory on your system. If you really want it create a `/home/{directory}/` but I would use a directory in `/`.
- create a group.
- add `user1` and `user2` to that group.
- set the directory to that group.

Command line style:

```
groupadd discworld
usermod -a -G discworld user1
usermod -a -G discworld user2
mkdir /Discworld/
chgrp discword /Discworld
```

And all users in group `discworld` (here `user1` and `user2`) can do what ever permissions is set for directory `/Discworld/`.

Answer (score 0):

One hack I've found to work is for user1 to copy the document to `/tmp`, then log-in as user2 and usually the document is still in `/tmp` for you to copy. Of course, if you wait too long or reboot, the document may be gone, but usually a logout then login does not clear `/tmp`.

The benefit of this of course is you don't need to fiddle with access permissions and groups, but this is definitely not the most scalable solution.